# GAE python backend for game loop

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm having a rough time trying to get a loop setup with GAE and backends. My goal: A main game loop to track timers (enemy move in 3 seconds, cooldown ready in 5 seconds, etc etc). I think a resident backend with a thread is the way to go. So far I have only been able to get a backend to show up in the dashboard after appcfg.py backends update. Now I'm just struggling to figure out the next step. Here are some specific questions:

1. how do I develop a backend thread if its not supported in the development server?
2. does using backends and a thread sound like a reasonable approach for a game loop?

the most helpful thing would be a basic example that includes backends.yaml, main app .py file, and backend .py code . This is how I imagine an example would work:

- a request is sent from the browser to the app.
- the app communicates to the backend instance and sets up a timer in a thread
- once the timer is complete... what happens next? response to browser, or back to app?

I've read the docs numerous times and its not sinking in anymore. I've tried to figure it out, but progress is extremely slow. And I can't find a useful, newbie-oriented example online. Any help would be much appreciated! thanks,

Comment: Straight off the bat I would say have your game loop client side, is it multiplayer?

Comment: Even if you're writing a multiplayer game, the game loop should still be in the client, and it should fetch world updates from the server regularly, not the other way around.

Comment: Yes, it is multiplier. so I run the timer in the client and verify it on the server? My idea was to use the "channel" service to push updates back to the browser. since the timer would be server side, I can be sure that it hasnt been tampered. And it seems more organized than computing AI in browsers and syncing it with other browsers. Whose browser should do the computing? If all browsers are computing a single enemy, wouldn't that get messy?

Answer (score 0):

1. google.appengine.api.background_thread does work on dev server
2. I dont know if this is a reasonable approach for multiplayer game

example:

front end:

```
<script>
onMessage = function(msg){
    console.log(msg.data)
}
channel = new goog.appengine.Channel('{{ token }}');
socket = channel.open();
socket.onmessage = onMessage;
</script>
```

testbackend.py

```
import logging, webapp2, time
from google.appengine.api import background_thread, channel

class Thread(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        token = self.request.get("token")
        t = background_thread.BackgroundThread(target=timed_message, args=[token])
        t.start()

def timed_message(token, *kwargs):
    logging.info(token)
    time.sleep(2)
    channel.send_message(token, "channel works")

pages = [
        ("/testbackend/start_thread", Thread),
    ]

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(pages, debug=True)
```

main.py

```
import webapp2, jinja2, os, logging
from google.appengine.api import backends, urlfetch, users, channel

JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

class IndexPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if not user:
            self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))
        token = channel.create_channel(user.user_id())
        template_values = {"token":token}
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('templates/index.html')
        self.response.write(template.render(template_values))

class TestAReq(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        url = backends.get_url("testbackend")+"/testbackend/start_thread"
        result = urlfetch.fetch(url, method="POST", payload="token="+user.user_id())
        self.response.write("abc")

pages = [
            ('/', IndexPage),
            ("/ajaxtest", TestAReq),
        ]
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(pages, debug=True)
```

app.yaml handlers:

```
handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /testbackend/.*
  script: testbackend.app

- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```